# Scaling at manjaro

Tags: manjaro

I have just installed manjaro linux and as I see I have wrong resolution or smth like that. All window fonts and all window parts are too small. I thought that I will be able to fix it in settings, but here I have all right. I thought maybe `xrandr` will help me to fix it, but I didn't manage to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably got the resolution fine. But window scaling is going to make everything super tiny at high resolutions.  Read this section of the arch wiki for help https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI